# Extract part of a image from a big image

Tags: windows, linux, image-editing

I have a 6 images , and each image has a certain section that i want to save as a separate image , the problem is that it has to be accurate because i am doing some animation using the sub-image so they should exactly . so I want to accurately extract a that part from each of the 6 images , i can't do it using a image editor in which i have to make the bounding box myself because it will not be accurate , is there any program that lets me do this by like defining a box using numerical values.

PS: I don't want to write matlab or opencv program for this .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) or [GraphiksMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/).  Both are very capable command line image editors that can easily do what you are asking. Of course you could also use an image editor and explictly define the size of your bounding box. Both Gimp and Photoshop have this functionality.

Comment: Thanks, how to do it using gimp ?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of the crop tool, which is essentially what you are doing. [Tutorial](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-crop.html)